# Can't create new model object within django rest framework model view set: 'User' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a django rest framework project. I am trying to override the create method so that if there are certain parameters or arguments passed into the url, it will ovverride some of the default informaiton passed in with the form.

I am doing that by creating the data object that will be used to create the new object. Right now, I am grabbing the user by using `request.user` but it is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError at /api/v2/preferences/namespace1/
'User' object is not subscriptable
```

and I am not sure how to fix it.

Here is my code for the mode view set create method override:

```
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated))
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request)
        namespace = self.kwargs.get('namespace', None)
        path = self.kwargs.get('path', None)
        if namespace is None and path is None:
            return super().create(request)
        if namespace and path is None:
            data = {
                "person":self.request.user,
                'version':request.POST['version'],
                'namespace':namespace,
                'path':request.POST['path'],
                'value':request.POST['value'],
                'user_id':request.user['id'],
            }
            return super().create(data)
        if namespace and path:
            data = {
                "person":self.request.user,
                'version':request.POST['version'],
                'namespace':namespace,
                'path':path,
                'value':request.POST['value'],
                'user_id':request.user['id'],
            }
            return super().create(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

`request.user` returns a `User` object from database, it is not a `dict`; hence your `request.user['id']` subscription operation will fail expectedly.

You need to get the `id` *attribute* of the User object:

```
request.user.id
```

So, make the `data` dict like:

```
data = {
    ...
    ...   
    'user_id': request.user.id,
}
```

Comment: ok thanks.  that worked. I am getting this `AttributeError at /api/v2/preferences/namespace1/
'dict' object has no attribute 'data'` is this because of the POST

Comment: @OmarJandali Where are you getting this? On which HTTP method?

Comment: So i am sending a post request from the django rest framework backend and I want to grab the data that is sent to the api and then just override the namespace if it is given or path if it is given. but I am submitting a post request from the django rest framework backend. i just want to grab that data in the viewset  create method.

Comment: @OmarJandali I don't understand it clearly. It would be better if you ask it as [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with all the details.

Comment: You should not input simply `data` to `super().create()` since the first argument of `create()` should be a `HttpRequest` object. That's why you get the `AttributeError` I think.